# como llenar un listview mediante otro en vb6

Tags: vb6

Tengo dos listview y una caja de texto donde realizo una busqueda y manda parte de la informacion a un listview y al hacer click en uno de los registros/campos/subitems, me manda la informacion completa al otro listview. El problema es que quiero que uno de los subitems del segundo listview me muestre la informacion de dos campos de mi tabla en la base de datos.

Ya realice la parte de la busqueda y el llenado del primer listview, ahora tengo el siguiente codigo a partir del listview1:

```
Private Sub ListView1_Click()
Call conexion

If ListView1.ListItems.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "Realiza una búsqueda para continuar", 16, "System"
Else
j = ListView1.SelectedItem
SQL = "select * from materiales where codigo='" & j & "'"
Set rsconection = MyBase.Execute(SQL)
If rsconection.EOF Then
Else
ListView2.ListItems.Clear
Do Until rsconection.EOF
With ListView2.ListItems.Add(, , rsconection("codigo"))
.SubItems(1) = rsconection("factor") & ""
.SubItems(2) = rsconection("umed") & ""

.SubItems(3) = rsconection("desing") & "" And ("desesp") & ""         
                                                                 
.SubItems(4) = rsconection("fraccionmx") & ""                   
rsconection.MoveNext                                           
End With                                                         
Loop
End If
End If
End Sub

Esta es la parte donde no se cual es la estructura que debo poner o si se puede realizar dicha tarea, los campos que quiero que aparescan en un mismo subitem son descripción en ingles y descripcion en español

.SubItems(3) = rsconection("desing") & "" And ("desesp") & ""
```